# JS Console for Browser Solidity?

Tags: remix, console

Is there any way to connect a console to Browser-Solidity's JavaScript-VM?  I'd like to send JS calls to contracts.

Comment: truffle has a console, but not BS AFAIK

Comment: You can use MIST itself?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not directly, but one can connect browser-solidity to a node running on your computer (under the tab with a cube). You can then use geth attach, node.js with web3 required, etc. to interact with the node you're running.

I would recommend [testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc) if you wish to do this. A private blockchain is probably overkill.